# Can I capture shell invocations from Perl?

Tags: perl, debugging, shell, shellexecute, system-calls

I have a Perl script which invokes other programs, i.e. it calls `system` and/or `exec` and/or `open` with a pipe and/or uses the backtick operator.

Can I run this script in such a way that it will print out the arguments to each of the above so that I can see what it is calling into?

For example a program like this **which I cannot modify**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub get_arg {return "argument$_[0]";}
system "./foo", get_arg(1), get_arg(2);
print `./foo abc def`;
```

Invoked something perhaps like this

> perl --shell-trace-on ./myscript.pl

Which will in this case output

```
./foo argument1 argument2
./foo abc def
```

It is acceptable to throw away myscript.pl's normal output or blend it with this trace.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So you want the script to see what the command looks like after shell expansion?

Comment: I want to capture executions of external programs and their arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is considered advanced Perl, but you can define subroutines in the `CORE::GLOBAL` namespace at compile time and hijack Perl's builtin functions.
Calling functions in the `CORE` namespace will invoke the original builtin functions.

```
BEGIN {
    # have to use a BEGIN block so these functions are defined before
    # run time
    *CORE::GLOBAL::system = sub {
        print STDERR "about to invoke system @_\n";
        return CORE::system(@_);
    };
    *CORE::GLOBAL::qx = sub {
        print STDERR "about to invoke qx/backticks @_\n";
        return CORE::qx(@_);
    };
    *CORE::GLOBAL::exec = sub { ... };
};
system("sleep 5");
print `ls`;
1;
```

To apply this feature to an arbitrary standalone script, you can put this code into a simple module (say, `ShellTrace.pm`), and then invoke `perl` with the `-MShellTrace` switch. (HT: perlman):

```
package ShellTrace;
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::system = sub { ... };
    *CORE::GLOBAL::qx = sub { ... };
    *CORE::GLOBAL::exec = sub { ... };
    *CORE::GLOBAL::open = sub { ... };
}
1;

$ perl -MShellTrace ./myscript.pl
about to invoke system ./foo argument1 argument2 
about to invoke qx/backticks ./foo abc def
...
```

Comment: Impressive trick, but it requires modifying the script. Is there a way to invoke the script unchanged but with the environment thus established?

Comment: Yes - put those changes in a `.pm` file (e.g. `ShellTrace.pm`, and invoke your script with `perl -MShellTrace ./myscript.pl`

Answer (score 1):

No, the system command does not put its executed command in any special variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub get_arg {return "argument$_[0]";}
my $command = './foo ' . join(' ', get_arg(1), get_arg(2));
print "$command\n";
my $resp = `$command`; # or system($command);
print `ls *bar*`;
```

Comment: Edited to clarify -- the script is immutable. I'm looking for a solution that's analogous to `strace`.